# How to add variable length array into a Vec?

Tags: rust

What is equivalent of list of lists in Python for Rust?

For example:

```
a=[]
a.append([1,2])
a.append([1,2,3])
a.append([1,2,3,4])
a.append([1,2,3])
```

I couldn’t find an example. I have tried with enums, Vector default types, but I couldn't add variable length array into another Vector.

I would like to have:

```
let mut v: Vec<[]> = vec![]; 
v.push((1,2));
v.push((1));
```

Comment: [A vector](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html).

Comment: Yes I have tried with various vec types such as Vec<(u8)>, Vec<_> etc but I cant added Vec.push((1)), Vec.push((1,2))

Comment: [See this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1f18331b1468da55fc9b4df4020a1f33&version=stable) for an equivalent to the Python version.

Comment: Oh My god. this simple. I am trying various non-sense. Shall I delete this question or add an example?

Comment: You cannot use tuples because tuples of different sizes are of different types. And when you push the first tuple then that determines the type of the vector. So you could only push the same kind of tuples there. Since the equivalent of a Python list is a vector, the equivalent of a list of lists is a vector of vectors.

Comment: I got confused by defining the vector. I was concentrating on Vec<> and trying how to define Vec<Vec> or Vec<[]>. This makes good sense now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think the examples so far lack an explanation what the actual type looks like (say you want to return it from a function). *list of lists* translates directly to *Vec of Vec*. So the type of a *Vec of Vec of small integers* could be `Vec<Vec<i8>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you tried? The straight translation of your example works:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![];
    a.push(vec![1, 2]);
    a.push(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    a.push(vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);
    a.push(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=830a1987e68aa975d172d680a4095ed8&version=stable)